# how to send post request in android

Tags: android

how to send post request in android
I use async http clint library 
I use this methode for get and I need this for post

```
client.get(getString(R.string.server2) + "culture_types", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {


            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("param1", "Test"); // Put parameter name 
client.post(Url, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {


        }
    }
});
```